# The sortable function of jquery ui doesn't work with body zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

It is not working properly because the cursor does not follow the elements of the grid, but it is as if there were no zoom.

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/4bwbwbow/

I found this workaround for the "draggable" feature:

JS

```
 var zoom = $('#canvas').css('zoom');
 var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
 var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();

 $('#dragme').draggable({
     drag: function(evt,ui)
     {
         // zoom fix
         ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
         ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);

         // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
         if (ui.position.left < 0) 
             ui.position.left = 0;
         if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth)
             ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();  
         if (ui.position.top < 0)
             ui.position.top = 0;
         if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight)
             ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();  

     }                 
 });
```

Do you think that I can apply it, in some way, to the "sortable" method, rather than "draggable"?

Answer (score 0):

I created a fairly functional workaround by creating a formula that reflect the primary zoom, change the zoom values, width, height, and font-size container and elements:

```
 body { zoom:0.5; } 

 #sortable { zoom: 2; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 225px; }  

 #sortable li { margin: 1.5px 1.5px 1.5px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 50px; height: 45px; font-size: 2em; text-align: center; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcg2aL8s/

This is the only solution that came to my mind.